# Wrong status code for failed autorization requirement in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created the web api with simple autorization via autorization requirments. My requirments code looks like:

```
public class TestRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }

public class TestHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TestRequirement> {
    protected override Task
        HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TestRequirement requirement) {
        //context.Succeed(requirement); --#1
        //context.Fail(); --#2
        /*if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext) {--#3
            mvcContext.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }*/
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Also, I updated `Startup.ConfigureServices(...)`:

```
        services.AddAuthorization(o => o.AddPolicy("Test", p => p.Requirements.Add(new TestRequirement())));
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, TestHandler>();
```

And I added apropriate attribute to controller: `[Authorize(Policy = "Test")]`

If I uncomment block #1 - it works as expected (I get my data). But when my code fails requiremnt (I comment #1), I get `500 Internal Server Error`.

Then, I tried to explicit fail the requirment (uncomment block #2) - same result. I know it isn't recommended but I wanted to try.

After this, I tried the more ugly workaround, I commented #2 and uncommented block #3. I got same 500 status code.

Just for fun, I implemented resources filter with the same behavior:

```
public class TestResourceFilterAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context) {
        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context) {
    }
}
```

Then, I replaced on controller my authorize attribute with `[TestResourceFilter]` and got `401 Unauthorized` as expected. But it the bad way to use resource filters.

What is wrong with my requirement implementation? And why I get 500 instead of 401 (or 403)?

**EDIT:** I found `InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.` in my log.
I saw samples with cookies scheme, but it isn't suitable for me. Because I want to implement stateless calls.

Comment: You are writing *server code*, there is no such thing as an error 500 in server code. You see the error 500 in the client, but that’s not where a problem appears. Look at your logs to see what is actually wrong with the server; you likely hit an exception, and that exception should tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @poke Good point, I will add exception handler and will see what is going on.

Comment: No, look at your logs! Exceptions are logged automatically.

Comment: Hm, I get 'InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.'

Comment: I want to implement stateless authorization.

Comment: It is quite strange that I didn't have this exception when a requirement is a success.

Comment: When the requirement fails, you are triggering a *authorization challenge*. Authorization challenges are handled by authentication schemes (in particular the `DefaultChallengeScheme` as the error tells you). – You really should set up a proper authentication handler here; whether you are stateless or stateful does not really matter. See the JwtBearer authentication as an example (which is also stateless); it has a [challenge handler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L194) that basically returns an error.

Comment: You are right. It is more logical to move it from Authorization to Authentication level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

poke's commnets pointed me that I implemented my functionality in wrong way. I tried to handle the security checking on authorization level, but I had to do it on authentication level. So my final code looks like:

```
public class TestHandlerOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions { }

internal class TestHandler : AuthenticationHandler<TestHandlerOptions> {
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() {
        if (await SomeCheckAsync()) {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(ClaimsName);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), null, ClaimsName);
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }

        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing or malformed 'Authorization' header.");
    }
}
```

Add next in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup` class:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => options.AddScheme(SchemeName, o => o.HandlerType = typeof(TestHandler)));
```

And authorize attribute looks like `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = SchemeName)]`

Comment: Remember to add the **public** (not _protected_) constructor for the `TestHandler` class. VS auto generates protected constructor which will fail to be used by the dependency injection system. (getting `xyz could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.` error.)

Comment: Thanks, @wye for your comment. I will take it into consideration.